# TortoiseGit context menu options disappeared

Tags: git, tortoisegit

For some reason, when TortoiseGit is installed for one user on a PC (Windows), if a second user gets an account, certain options are missing from the context menu and apparently cannot simply be restored from the context-menu settings. 
How do I get e.g. file "History" back?

[image: Context items missing]

**Edit**

What I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Do the entries show up when you press the shift key when opening the context menu?

Comment: Are no options displayed at all or are just "some missing"? - The screenshot isn't complete on the right side.

Comment: The options that I'm missing are supposed to be on the left here. There are options on the right, but not the "History" option that I mainly miss

Comment: Are you talking about "Git Show Log"? or hwo is the exact entry named?

Comment: I have added an update, from my old PC with the options. Now I'm thinking it's not actually part of TG maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseGit is fully configurable (for each user) on which entries to show by default and also which entries to show directly on the context menu and which to include in the submenu.

In order to configure the entries, open TortoiseGit settings and go to "Context menu". Here you can select which entries to include directly on the context menu.

Under "Set Extended Menu Item" you can select items which hidden by default and also visible if you press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when opening the context menu.

Update: The entries you are looking for are part of GitSheetah or Git Extensions.

Comment: Holding `[Shift]` enabled the missing Git menu items to display. Although I still don't know why I needed to hold `[Shift]` as I didn't just a few days ago...